# How to watch for new records added to model in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, sails.js, message

I'm trying to push a message for when a user sends a message to a certain certain Id (within an User model) in a user to user chat messaging system. I can't get it to work, nor do I know how to get started. I have this in my `Messaging` controller:

```
sendAndReceiveMsgs: function(req, res) {

    if (req.isSocket && req.param('message') && req.param('to')) {

        var message = req.param('message'),
            from = req.user.id,
            to = req.param('to');

        Messaging.create({ message: message, from: from, to: to })
            .exec(function (err, created) {
                console.log('sent');
        });

    } else if (req.isSocket) {

        Messaging.find({ where: { to: req.user.id }, limit: 1, sort: 'id DESC' })
        .exec(function(err, messages) {
            if(messages.length > 0){
                console.log(message.length + " new messages");
            } else {
                console.log("No new messages");
            }
            Messaging.subscribe(req.socket, message);
            Messaging.watch(req);
            Messaging.publishCreate({ id: message[0].id, message: message[0].message });
        });

    } else if (!req.isSocket) {

        return res.notFound();

    }

}
```

However, it doesn't push further new messages to the user (meant for him). Any clue? I really don't understand this, and don't know where to go from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please show the client side code too.
One thing I noticed is that you're using subscribe but it's used only to see messages emittted by .publishUpdate(), .publishDestroy(), .publishAdd() and .publishRemove(). Not sure if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use io.socket.on in your client. See the documentation [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.io.js/io.socket.on.html).
The eventIdentity if your using pub/sub methods are also the model name.